# Will the Mersenne Twister PRNG eventually produce all integer sequences of a certain length?

Tags: algorithms, pseudo-random-generators

I'm attempting to use the MT19937 variant of the Mersenne Twister PRNG to accomplish something.  Whether or not this something is feasible depends upon the answers to these two questions:

What is the greatest value of **m** for which the following statements hold true:

1 - For all seed values, the algorithm eventually produces every integer list of length **m**.

2 - There exists a seed value for which the algorithm would eventually produce a given integer list of length **m**.

Comment: This is in general hard to answer. If you explained your application to us, it might make it easier for us to help you. For 2, $m$ is bounded by the size of the key. If you wanted an algorithm with these two properties for given $m$, you can use a running counter initialized at the seed value.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Would you please link to a source or else explain how you know that "for 2, _m_ is bounded by the size of the key"?

Comment: Ah - sorry, I missed the "eventually" part.

Comment: Well, Wikipedia says that this PRG has a period of $2^{19937}−1$, so, assuming 32 bit integers that gives us an upper bound $m \leq \frac{\ln (2^{19937}−1)}{32 \ln 2} \approx 623$.

At first I wrongly assumed that the sequences can't overlap and using Lambert W got $m \leq 622$. It's weird how little difference this made...